# Body <header> becomes transparent using bootstrap layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to build a page with sticky header and footer, using bootstrap. Started out with page template from [bootstrap sticky footer example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/). Current code looks like something like this :

HTML

```
<body>
 <header>header</header>
 <div id="main">
  <div id="content"></div>
 </div>
 <footer>footer</footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
html, body { height:400px; color: white; }

div#main
{
min-height: 100%;
/*height: auto !important;*/
height: 100%;
margin : -56px 0;
padding:  56px 0;
background-color:black;
}

header { height: 56px; background-color: #355d98; }
footer { height: 56px; background-color: #355d98; }
div#content { height: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

*, *:before, *:after {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Same code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LU27/)

My problem is that header has transparent background, event though is has a background color assigned.

```
background-color: #355d98;
```

What is causing this ?

**EDIT 1** : In this code I fixed height to 400px, on my page it's 100%, so I need these lines to create sticky header and footer (same method in bootstrap template)

```
margin : -56px 0;
padding:  56px 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the negative `top-margin` from the `#main` div. As you have specified the -ve margin, so you `#main` overwrite the `header`.

```
div#main {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -56px; /*only applied bottom margin*/
padding: 56px 0;
background-color: black;
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4LU27/3/)

Comment: this will not solve my problem, I need those negative margins to make sticky header and footer work (my project page height is 100% instead of 400px)

Comment: @GytisŠk if you see the fiddle, I have also used `height:100%` for body, not the 400px.

Comment: Sorry, but this isnt working either. Whole page has to be 100%, while div#main has to be (100% - header.height - footer.height)

Comment: @GytisŠk okey got it, So just remove the top margin and remain the bottom margin as it is.See the updated post. I have changed the margin property.

Comment: If you scroll down you will see that html, body are overflowing - total height is more than 100%.

Comment: ok, I think I figured a solution (a workaround perhaps). Just give header position:absolute and remove negative top margin. I never shouldve done the negative margin thing on header, cause in the template it was only used on footer. It is still strange though, why footer is ok and header isnt.